# WPF DataTrigger fires late?

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem is that a WPF `DataTrigger` combined with a `MultiValueConverter` does not pick up on a change in Type, or rather, it seems to do so too late, resulting in a Casting exception.

**Desired** is a `ListView` which displays two different types: mostly `Sections` (like Math101 in the pic) and also `Banners` (like Summer) interspersed among the sections. A `Banner` contains a `Button`(the + in the pic below) which is used to add a `Section` below that banner, via a Command that adds the new section to the CompositeCollection in the right place.
[image]
**The Problem** is that sometimes (!) when I add a `Section` below the first Banner (Summer in the example) the `DataTrigger` does not pick up on the new `Section` and instead seems to view it as `Banner` resulting in a casting error in the ValueConverter
which supplies the color for the Banner. The CompositeCollection is correct, I can verify that.

**Code**  (irrelevant details omitted)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Data.TheAcademicUnit},Path=CurrentTimetabling.SectionListAndBanners}"> 
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle> <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource SectionListItemStructure}">
<!-- much omitted about how to display a section's information in a GridView -->
```

and then in the parent control's resources

```
<Style x:Key="SectionListItemStructure" TargetType="ListViewItem">
 <Style.Triggers>                
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource datatypeconverter}}" Value="Section">
   <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}"/>        
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </DataTrigger>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource datatypeconverter}}" Value="Semester">
   <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.AddSectionCommand}" Content="+"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
         <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
           <Setter Property="Background">
             <Setter.Value>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SemesterToColor}">
                 <Binding Source="{x:Static local:Data.TheAcademicUnit}" Path="CurrentTimetabling.TheSemesters"/>
                  <Binding />
                 </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
              </Style>
             </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
      </Control Template>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Trigger>
 </Style>
```

and finally the Converter in which the Exception occurs

```
public class SemesterToColor : IMultiValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
 if (values[0] != null && values[1] != null)
  {
    ObservableCollection<Semester> semesters = (ObservableCollection<Semester>)values[0];
    Semester semester = (Semester)values[1];           
    //details about how to set the color via SolidColorBrush omitted
   }
   }
}
//ConvertBack etc... 
}
```

The exception occurs in the cast of `values[1]` to Semester, as `values[1]` is being fed the new `Section`, even though the `DataTrigger` should being switching to Section mode, not Semester mode.

I can route around this by just adding the following to the beginning of the converter, and everything works fine. But why do I need to do that? Why is the DataTrigger not switching? Am I missing something?

```
if (values[1].GetType() == typeof(Section))
 {
   return Binding.DoNothing;
 }
```

EDIT: below are some relevant portions of `CurrentTimetabling`

```
public CompositeCollection SectionListAndBanners { get; set; }
```

is set up originally via

```
private void SetUpSectionsAndBannersList(ObservableCollection<Semester> theSemesters)
{           
 SectionListAndBanners.Clear();
  foreach (Semester semester in theSemesters)
   {
     CollectionContainer cc = new CollectionContainer();
     cc.Collection = semester.SectionList;
     if (theSemesters.Count > 1)
      { SectionListAndBanners.Add(semester); }                              
      SectionListAndBanners.Add(cc);      
    }
}
```

(the intention being that one only sees the banners in a multi-semester
situation.) A new section, added  via the + button in some banner, is added to the `SectionList` for that semester, and hence automatically to `SectionListAndBanners` as the CompositeCollection picks up automatically on additions to its constituent elements.

Comment: Can you show the structure of the class you are trying to display / bind to, and what is the INTENDED primise on which control to be displayed based on your multi-part considerations.  It might make more sense seeing the class.  Please EDIT your post to provide the additional code.

Comment: @DRapp I've added some details on how SectionListAndBanners is formed, is that what you have in mind?